# Can attribute directives transclude?

Tags: angularjs, transclusion

I want slotted transclusion, and I've seen examples of element directives like this:

```
<my-directive>
    <slot-a></slot-a>
    <slot-b></slot-b>
</my-directive>
```

I want to know if it must be an element directive. I'd like to do something like this:

```
<div my-directive>
    <slot-a></slot-a>
    <slot-b></slot-b>
</div>
```

Is this possible? I can't find any documentation saying it can or can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can—at least in recent versions of AngularJS. The snippet below is a variation of the element directive in the [multi-slot transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude#multi-slot-transclusion) section.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('multiSlotTranscludeExample', [])
    .directive('pane', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: {
          'title': '?paneTitle',
          'body': 'paneBody',
          'footer': '?paneFooter'
        },
        template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
          '<div class="title" ng-transclude="title">Fallback Title</div>' +
          '<div ng-transclude="body"></div>' +
          '<div class="footer" ng-transclude="footer">Fallback Footer</div>' +
          '</div>'
      };
    })
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.title = 'Lorem Ipsum';
        $scope.link = 'https://google.com';
        $scope.text = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor...';
      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="multiSlotTranscludeExample">
  <style>
    .title,
    .footer {
      background-color: gray
    }
  </style>
  
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input ng-model="title" aria-label="title">
    <br/>
    <textarea ng-model="text" aria-label="text"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <div pane>
      <pane-title>
        <a ng-href="{{link}}" ng-bind="title"></a>
      </pane-title>
      <pane-body>
        <p ng-bind="text"></p>
      </pane-body>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```